# Validación Fechas AJAX y Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, yii2

Buen día.

Necesito validar 2 fechas en por Ajax trabajando con Yii2 y MySQL, que requiero tengo la fecha actual que la saco por código PHP, las dos fechas que tengo son
1. Fecha actual
2. Fecha de accidente

Necesito que si registro un accidente y la fecha del accidente es de ya hace mas de 4 dias me genere una ventana modal preguntando ¿Por que se demoro en el registro del accidente? y guardar eso en un campo de la tabla logs que estoy generando, lo he estado tratando de hacer pero casi no conozco el funcionamiento de Ajax.

Este es el código con el que estoy comparando las fechas en PHP.

```
public function actionComparar($id) {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $fecha_actual=date('Y-m-d');
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($fecha_actual=date('Y-m-d'));
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($model->fecha_hora);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format(' %R%a días ');  }
```

Las fechas las guardo en la base de datos en los campos.

```
fch_registro_gm  -> es el dia actual -> timestamp

fecha_hora -> es la fecha del accidente -> datetime
```

Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Cuál es el error del código?

Comment: Hola no no es error del codigo lo que pasa es que pregunto porque no lo se hacer y no encuentro buena informacion sobre validaciones en Ajax en internet, soy novato trabajando con Ajax